# Load json by latest input - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm building an app where the user gets to see his newest posts on his profile, currently I'm loading in the jsons going through the list from top to bottom.

Is there an easy way to switch this around, in other words load the newest inputs, this way it can show the 'recent activity'.

This is my code to get the current data:

```
$http.get('URL')
        .then(function(result) {
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(data, key) {
                if(data.userId === authenticated.profile.user_id) {
                    $scope.posts.push(data);
            } 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how are you using the array of datas in your view ,  you can use filter in angularJs to show the recent data based on the timeStamp or based on your requirement ,

Instead of using `push` method you could use `unshift` to add the data  from the beginning of the Array.As a result new data will be at the first data item in the array as below

```
 angular.forEach(result.data, function(data, key) {
                if(data.userId === authenticated.profile.user_id) {
                    $scope.posts.unshift(data);
            }
```

If your data has timeStamp you can sort data based on that using filter as below

**template**

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy :'created_at':true "></div>
```

refer : [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: This works! Would u recommend me doing it this way or using the timestamp?

Comment: @Pexilius as data coming from server , It would be safe to trust that data :) as result , you can make use of the properties in the data which in your case created_at and sort using orderBy filter . I have updated answer with the same .

Comment: Alright great, should I keep the unshift aswell or revert it back to '$scope.posts.push(data)' ? I did both and they give the same result. I'm guessing the filter overrides the $scope integration methode. If I keep it to unshift, I won't be an issue will it?

Comment: @Pexilius I would recommend you use with filter with created_at properties as the data coming from the backed and angularJs orderBy filter will sort based on the created at time

Comment: Or if u don't wanna use filter you can modify your posts array based on created_at properties in the arrays using JavaScript map method and and sort by your own

Comment: Yes that I know and I've integrated it, but should I change the method back to push or just keep it unshift? Or does that not matter?

Comment: If you use filter you can use push , no problem with that ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a timestamp somewhere in your returned JSON? To sort by "recent" you need to provide some sort of way to signify this in your return(s).

Comment: Yes the json returns a 'created_at':
Object {_id: "5740bc9d321217c418db8c28", created_at: "2016-05-21T19:53:01.102Z", userId: "118000609287736585411", post_title: "Testing data"…}